# Want to send OTP via web application in java without using gsm modem

Tags: java

I have made a web application in java and I want to send OTP to mobile no. of users if they forget their password. I want to send free sms over the internet without using GSM modem. Please provide me the code for it

Comment: please provide me a sundae ice cream.

Comment: @ArnonZilca Really !

Answer (score 1):

Try with this example code.If it return 402,then the message was successfully sent.If it return 408,that means the message was not sent.

```
public String sendSMS(String mob_No,String msg)
{  
            String result="408";
    int TIMEOUT_VALUE = 500;
    try{
     String username = "enter your username";
     String password = "Enter your password";
     String senderid = "Enter your senderid";
     String message = msg;//"new message system....!";
     String mobileNo = mob_No ;         
     HttpURLConnection connection = null;            
     URL url = new URL("Enter the url");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setFollowRedirects(true);
        connection.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_VALUE);

        String smsservicetype = "singlemsg"; // For single message.
            String query = "username=" + URLEncoder.encode(username)
                + "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(password)
                + "&smsservicetype=" + URLEncoder.encode(smsservicetype)
                + "&content=" + URLEncoder.encode(message) + "&mobileno="
                + URLEncoder.encode(mobileNo) + "&senderid="
                + URLEncoder.encode(senderid);

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String
            .valueOf(query.length()));
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
            "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows 98; DigExt)");

        // open up the output stream of the connection
            DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(connection
                    .getOutputStream());

        // write out the data
        int queryLength = query.length();
        output.writeBytes(query);
        // output.close();
        // get ready to read the response from the cgi script
        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(connection
                    .getInputStream());
        String tempres="";
        // read in each character until end-of-stream is detected
        for (int c = input.read(); c != -1; c = input.read())
             {System.out.print((char) c);
             tempres+=String.valueOf((char) c);
             }

        result=tempres.substring(0, tempres.indexOf(","));
        input.close();
            System.out.println("Resp Code:" + connection.getResponseCode());
        System.out.println("Resp Message:"
                + connection.getResponseMessage());
     }
    catch(Exception e)
    {           
        e.printStackTrace();    
        System.out.println("More than " + TIMEOUT_VALUE + " elapsed.");

    }

    return result;
 }
```